# C++ acess object via pointer instead of direct access

Tags: c++, performance, pointers

In some code i have seen the following:
`(&object)->something`.

1. Is there any advantage to `object.something` ?
2. Does the compiler somehow optimize such code, or is it faster in any way?

Comment: Does `object` overload unary `&`?

Comment: No, it does not

Comment: Can you show an example of the code you found where they do this?  Unless `&` is overloaded I see no reason to do this.

Comment: It could be that someone wrote object->something and the compiler rejected it, so he "corrected" his code...

Comment: I fear that i can not remember where exactly i found it, but your answer was all i was searching for.

Comment: Yet, does the compiler optimize such code?

Comment: It could be the result of a global search-and-replace.  Some singleton object that used to be referenced by a pointer, and somebody decided just to make it a global static object:  `s/object_ptr/(&object)/g`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `operator&` is not overloaded it's essentially the same https://godbolt.org/g/iPTjRY:

```
auto v_1 = f_1.get(); 
auto v_2 = (&f_1)->get();
```

resolved to pretty much the same:

```
lea rax, [rbp-12]               ; load object address
mov rdi, rax                    ; move object address into rdi, not sure why not just: 'lea rdi, [rbp-12]'
call Foo::get() const           ; invoke the subroutine
mov DWORD PTR [rbp-4], eax      ; save the result at [rbp-4]
```

(already with no optimizations they are the same; with optmizations turned on... the entire calls get discarded, so that's left for the curious reader)